# LateInitializationError: Field 'insertFunction has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, search, lazy-initialization

I'm new to flutter and really stuck.I am trying to create a search function that calls a list in my Sqfite database, using a keyword. The database all works fine, but when I insert a keyword in my searchbar that part of the app crashes with the following error:

LateInitializationError: Field 'insertFunction' has not been initialized.Im using the insertFunction and deleteFunction parameters and the constructor, but my createState throws an error then that it needs insert and deleteFunction data, which I cannto do as one cannot pass logic into createState.

Any help will be much appreciated. I need to solve my createState problem and my Lateinitialization problem.

Here is the code:

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();//createState is throwing an error and 
                                                       as that I insert insertFunction and 
                                                       deleteFunction here. But if i do, it 
                                                      also say I should not put logic into 
                                                      createState. 
         }

   class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
   late final Function insertFunction;
   late final Function deleteFunction;
   var db = DatabaseConnect();
   String keyword = '';

      _SearchPageState({required this.insertFunction,required this.deleteFunction,});

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Search My Clients'),
          leading: GestureDetector(
           onTap: () {
           Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homePage');
          },
          child: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
           ),
         ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
           Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: TextField(
            autofocus: true,
             decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'keyword',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                onChanged: (value) {
                keyword = value;
                 setState(() {});
                },
               ),
             ),
              FutureBuilder(
               future: db.searchContacts(keyword),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) const Text('error');
                var data = snapshot.data;
                var datalength = data!.length;

                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                 return datalength == 0
                    ? const Center(
                        child: Text('no data found'),
                      )
                    : Container(
                        child: LimitedBox(
                          maxHeight: 200,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            itemCount: datalength,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) => CustomerCard(
                              id: data[i].id,
                              title: data[i].title,
                              name: data[i].name,
                              phone: data[i].phone,
                              fax: data[i].fax,
                              email: data[i].email,
                              street: data[i].street,
                              city: data[i].city,
                              town: data[i].town,
                              code: data[i].code,
                              isExpanded: data[i].isExpanded,
                              insertFunction: insertFunction,
                              deleteFunction: deleteFunction,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                        } else {
                        return const Center(
                       child: Text('no data found'),
                              );
                             }
                           }),
                           ],
                          ),
                          ),
                        );
                       }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should be

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState(); 
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  insertFunction(){
    //function body goes here
  } 

  deleteFunction(){
    //function body goes here
  }

  var db = DatabaseConnect();
  String keyword = '';
  //the rest goes here
```

Comment: Hi Abdallah. Thank you for your help. It solved my problem. I was basically using the same template, but one in  Stateless to build the list of data and another in Stateful to build the list but also to do the search on the list of items. My code in Stateless to build the list of data was fine, but I was having difficulty to call the same function used in the Stateless code in my Stateful code. I simply re-created the functions as you indicated and it worked.